# How to count unique values over time in sparklyr (example given)?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data.table, sparklyr

I am trying to calculate unique devices seen in last 10 minutes from a timestamp(rounded off to minutes). I can do that in data.table , but no idea how to replicate same in sparklyr in R. 540 refers to # seconds added to current timestamp.

Example is provided below to explain my problem.

### Given Data

```
df<-data.frame(device_subscriber_id=c("x","a","z","x","a","z","x","y","a","z"),
                  start_timestamp=c("2020-12-11 14:21:00","2020-12-11 14:22:00","2020-12-11 14:23:00",
                                    "2020-12-11 14:26:00","2020-12-11 14:24:00","2020-12-11 14:25:00",
                                    "2020-12-11 14:26:00","2020-12-11 14:28:00","2020-12-11 14:31:00","2020-12-11 14:38:00"))

df$start_timestamp<-as.POSIXct(df$start_timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt<-setDT(df)
```

### Expected Data

```
expected_dt<-dt[dt[ , .(start_timestamp3=start_timestamp, start_timestamp2 = start_timestamp - 540, device_subscriber_id)], 
             on = .(start_timestamp >= start_timestamp2, start_timestamp<=start_timestamp3), 
             allow.cartesian = TRUE][ , .(unique_devices_seen = uniqueN(device_subscriber_id)),by = .(start_timestamp = start_timestamp + 540)]

expected_dt

   start_timestamp unique_devices_seen
   2020-12-11 14:21:00                   1
   2020-12-11 14:22:00                   2
   2020-12-11 14:23:00                   3
   2020-12-11 14:26:00                   3
   2020-12-11 14:24:00                   3
   2020-12-11 14:25:00                   3
   2020-12-11 14:28:00                   4
   2020-12-11 14:31:00                   4
   2020-12-11 14:38:00                   2
```

Comment: Recommended watch (in `data.table` "non-equi-joins" are usually referred to as "theta joins" in SQL context IME): https://databricks.com/session/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use SQL window function `OVER` between the current row and preceding 540 seconds. The `count(distinct device_subscriber_id)` throughs `Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Distinct window functions are not supported`. A work around is to collect the set of unique ids and return the size of the array. The timestamps were converted to epoch in order to use the range values in seconds.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
sc <- spark_connect(master="local[4]", version = "3.0.1")

sdf <- copy_to(sc, df, name = "df", overwrite = TRUE)

sdf_sql(sc, "
SELECT 
  start_timestamp,
  size(collect_set(device_subscriber_id) 
       OVER (ORDER BY start_ts_epoch ASC 
             RANGE BETWEEN 540 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as unique_devices_seen
FROM (SELECT *, unix_timestamp(start_timestamp) as start_ts_epoch FROM `df`)")
```

Result:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
   start_timestamp     unique_devices_seen
   <dttm>                            <int>
 1 2020-12-11 13:21:00                   1
 2 2020-12-11 13:22:00                   2
 3 2020-12-11 13:23:00                   3
 4 2020-12-11 13:24:00                   3
 5 2020-12-11 13:25:00                   3
 6 2020-12-11 13:26:00                   3
 7 2020-12-11 13:26:00                   3
 8 2020-12-11 13:28:00                   4
 9 2020-12-11 13:31:00                   4
10 2020-12-11 13:38:00                   2
```

Reference [Spark SQL Window Functions API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html)

---

Bonus: if the missing timestamps are desired you need to join the device's data with a table containing all possible timestamps. The missing timestamp will have device id as nulls and will not contribute to the count.

```
df_ts <- data.frame(start_timestamp=seq(min(df$start_timestamp), max(df$start_timestamp), by = "min"))
sdf_ts <- copy_to(sc, df_ts, name = "df_ts", overwrite = TRUE)

sdf_sql(sc, "
SELECT DISTINCT
  start_timestamp
  , size(collect_set(device_subscriber_id) 
         OVER (ORDER BY start_ts_epoch ASC 
               RANGE BETWEEN 540 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as unique_devices_seen
  , concat_ws(',', collect_set(device_subscriber_id)
                   OVER (ORDER BY start_ts_epoch ASC 
                   RANGE BETWEEN 540 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as unique_devices_seen_csv
FROM (SELECT 
        device_subscriber_id
        , df_ts.start_timestamp
        , unix_timestamp(df_ts.start_timestamp) as start_ts_epoch
      FROM df
      FULL JOIN df_ts ON (df.start_timestamp = df_ts.start_timestamp))") %>% print(n=30)
```

Note that I added `unique_devices_seen_csv` to show what is going on behind the scene. It concatenates the device ids of the sliding window.

Result:

```
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
   start_timestamp     unique_devices_seen unique_devices_seen_csv
   <dttm>                            <int> <chr>                  
 1 2020-12-11 13:21:00                   1 x                      
 2 2020-12-11 13:22:00                   2 x,a                    
 3 2020-12-11 13:23:00                   3 z,x,a                  
 4 2020-12-11 13:24:00                   3 z,x,a                  
 5 2020-12-11 13:25:00                   3 z,x,a                  
 6 2020-12-11 13:26:00                   3 z,x,a                  
 7 2020-12-11 13:27:00                   3 z,x,a                  
 8 2020-12-11 13:28:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
 9 2020-12-11 13:29:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
10 2020-12-11 13:30:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
11 2020-12-11 13:31:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
12 2020-12-11 13:32:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
13 2020-12-11 13:33:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
14 2020-12-11 13:34:00                   4 z,y,x,a                
15 2020-12-11 13:35:00                   3 y,x,a                  
16 2020-12-11 13:36:00                   2 y,a                    
17 2020-12-11 13:37:00                   2 y,a                    
18 2020-12-11 13:38:00                   2 z,a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer , it does answer my question . Just an additional request , Is it possible to fill missing timestamps (not given in original dataset) , for example from row 9 to row 10 ( in your final output) , there is no timestamps & no unique devices numbers from 13:32 to 13:37 . Thanks in advance , I will accept this answer anyway post your feedback

Comment: @YogeshKumar that's technically a second question but I answered it anyway. Please consider changeging the title of the question so it reflects the actual problem the code is solving. For example: _how to count unique values over time in sparklyr_

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL counts, we can use [dbi](/questions/tagged/dbi) to query the Spark cluster:

```
library(data.table)
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
copy_to(sc, dt)

sdf_sql(sc, "
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dt1.device_subscriber_id) as unique_devices_seen
, dt2.start_timestamp

FROM dt dt1
INNER JOIN dt dt2 ON dt1.start_timestamp >= dt2.start_timestamp - INTERVAL 9 minutes
                   AND dt1.start_timestamp <= dt2.start_timestamp

GROUP BY dt2.start_timestamp

ORDER BY start_timestamp
           ")


## # Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
##   unique_devices_seen start_timestamp    
##                 <dbl> <dttm>             
## 1                   1 2020-12-11 19:21:00
## 2                   2 2020-12-11 19:22:00
## 3                   3 2020-12-11 19:23:00
## 4                   3 2020-12-11 19:24:00
## 5                   3 2020-12-11 19:25:00
## 6                   3 2020-12-11 19:26:00
## 7                   4 2020-12-11 19:28:00
## 8                   4 2020-12-11 19:31:00
## 9                   2 2020-12-11 19:38:00
```

SQL seems to be a good middle ground - [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) lends itself very well to translating to SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this approach, but is extremely slow to execute even for a smaller dataset , I have 100 GB dataset , so this makes tough !

Comment: I've never used Spark so I assumed it was part of Spark using a local connection. I edited from `DBI::dbGetQuery` to `sparklyr::sdf_sql` and the performance seems the same as the other answer now.